# Green Dao, ContentProvider generation

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, greendao

how to use this template GreenDao generator to generate ContentProvider class:
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src-template/content-provider.ftl

And what it means this parameters:

```
public static final String BASE_PATH = "${contentProvider.basePath}";
```

https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src-template/content-provider.ftl#L28

```
private static final String PK = ${entity.classNameDao}.Properties.${entity.pkProperty.propertyName?cap_first}.columnName;
```

https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src-template/content-provider.ftl#L36

And how i can implement THIS:

`<#if contentProvider.isReadOnly()>`
https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO/blob/master/DaoGenerator/src-template/content-provider.ftl#L80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public static final String BASE_PATH = "${contentProvider.basePath}";` - it is TABLE NAME

```
private static final String PK = ${entity.classNameDao}.Properties.${entity.pkProperty.propertyName?cap_first}.columnName;
```

- it is Primary Column Name, for example:

```
private static final String PK = MYTABLENAMEDao.Properties.Id.columnName;
```

I do it ContentProvider DAO and it work fine!

Answer (score 1):

Each entity has its own ContentProvider for now, just call addContentProvider of your entities.

for example :

```
        Entity clientServer = schema.addEntity("ClientServer");
        clientServer.addIdProperty();
        clientServer.addIntProperty("tedadMorajeat");
        clientServer.addLongProperty("clientId");
        clientServer.addLongProperty("serverId");           
        clientServer.addContentProvider();
```